# Why Delphi will create a seperate .rc file for each configuration of the project when adding new Language?

Tags: delphi, localization

I am using Delphi XE3. My project contains 4 configurations, i.e., 32bit Debug, 32bit Release, 64bit Debug, 64bit Release.

When I add a new language for Chinese, the new project `Project1.CHS` contains one copy of the form, `Unit1.dfm`, that is correct since all the configurations share the same Form. However, it will create a separate `.rc` file for each configuration of the original project. For example, for 32bit Debug, it will create `Project_DRC.rc` under Win32 -> Debug.

See below:

[image]

I have checked these `.rc` files and they all contain the same strings. So, why does Delphi bother to make 4 of them? It is very inconvenient since I need to translate the strings 4 times. Though, with the Repository I can copy the translations from one place to another, but why doesn't Delphi keep ONE copy of the `.rc` file which can be shared among all the configurations? That will be much easier for us.

More severely, each time when I need to build a different configuration in the main project, I always need to click the "Update to localized project" menu item, before building `Projct1.CHS`, otherwise, it will not build the same configuration as the main project if I simply build it. That is very inconvenient.